# Explain a step for me

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Can someone please explain the high-lighted step to me? How does he get this result?

Comment: Note that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$$
and of course we have a generalization: for example

$$(ABCD)^{-1}=D^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$$

Comment: You're welcome:)